# How to create sum of columns in Pandas based on a conditional of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to sum two columns of the DataFrame to create a third column where the value in the third column is equal to the sum of the positive elements of the other columns. I have tried the below and just receive a column of NaN values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[-1, 2], [-2, 2], [1, -3], [1, -4], [ -2 , -2]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b'])

df['Sum of Positives'] = 0

df['Sum of Positives'] = df.loc[df.a > 0 ,'a'] +df.loc[df.b >0 , 'b']
```

DataFrame:

[image]

Comment: expected output?

Comment: df['Sum of Positives'] = [ 2 , 2 , 1, 1 , 0]

Comment: And how did you calculate them? It's still obscure to me how to get `[2, 2, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Sorry , I put that in incorrectly , edited my comment to reflect what it should be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`df.mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) here and fill value less than 0 i.e negative value with 0 and do [**`df.sum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) over axis 1.

```
df['sum of pos'] = df.mask(df<0, 0).sum(axis=1)

   a  b  sum of pos
0 -1  2           2
1 -2  2           2
2  1 -3           1
3  1 -4           1
4 -2 -2           0
```

### Few NumPy hacks that are useful here.

- #### Using [`np.copyto`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html)

  ```
  t = np.copy(df.values)
  np.copyto(t, 0, where=df.values<0)
  df['sum of pos'] = t.sum(axis=1)
  ```
- #### Using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

  ```
  df['sum of pos'] = np.where(df.values<0, 0, df.values).sum(axis=1)
  ```
- #### Using [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

  ```
  df['sum of pos'] = np.clip(df.values, 0, None).sum(axis=1)
  ```
- #### Using [`np.ma.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.array.html)

  ```
  m = np.ma.array(df.values, mask=df.values<0, fill_value=0)
  df['sum of pos'] = m.filled().sum(axis=1)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply, and subset on the positives:

```
df['Sum of Positives']  = df.apply(lambda x:sum(x[x>0]),axis=1)

    a   b   Sum of Positives
0   -1  2   2
1   -2  2   2
2    1 -3   1
3    1 -4   1
4   -2 -2   0
```

Comment: `apply` will be far slower than the `mask` solution for example

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `clip`

```
df.clip(lower=0).sum(1)
Out[19]: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove negative values with `clip`.

```
>>> df['Sum of Positives'] = df.clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)
>>> df
   a  b  Sum of Positives
0 -1  2                 2
1 -2  2                 2
2  1 -3                 1
3  1 -4                 1
4 -2 -2                 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because df.loc[condition, col] filters out rows not matching with the condition so you end up summing positive values with empty ones.
What you would like here is to replace in your columns negative values by zero and the sum the columns:

```
df['Sum of Positives'] = df.applymap(lambda x: max(x,0)).sum(axis=1)
```